# How to disable spell check for certain file types

Tags: filetype, spell-checking

How can I disable spell check for files likes yaml, json?

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your init.vim or .vimrc

```
autocmd FileType yaml,json setlocal nospell
```

Also, if you open a file and want to to disable the spell check:

```
:set nospell
```

Comment: Or even better, use your `after/ftplugin` directory.